# vb .net memory grows but process is stable

Tags: .net, memory-management, windows-7, ram, berkeley-db

I'm developing a .net application that stores some data every 300ms in a b-tree berkeley db.
I'm experiencing a strange RAM behaviour: the process of my application is using 60mb of RAM and it doesn't grow. However the pc RAM decreases slowly (in a few hours) until the pc stops working due to memory unavailable. I have 4 gb of RAM installed in my PC.

This is what i do in my application (more or less):

```
//Sub called every 300 ms  //lstTags containst 1000 objects

Public Sub InsertReceivedEvents(ByVal arBytesToInsert As Byte(), ByVal dtTimestamp As DateTime)

    For Each oMyTag As Tag In lstTags

        Select Case oMyTag.iDataType

            Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataBOOL
                arTempArray = New Byte(0) {}
                Array.Copy(arBytesToInsert, oMyTag.iTagOffset, arTempArray, 0, 1)

            Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataINT
                arTempArray = New Byte(1) {}
                Array.Copy(arBytesToInsert, oMyTag.iTagOffset, arTempArray, 0, 2)

            Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataREAL
                arTempArray = New Byte(3) {}
                Array.Copy(arBytesToInsert, oMyTag.iTagOffset, arTempArray, 0, 4)

            Case TagDataTypeEnumerator.eTypeOfDataSTRING
                arTempArray = New Byte(49) {}
                Array.Copy(arBytesToInsert, oMyTag.iTagOffset, arTempArray, 0, 50)

        End Select

        Try

            //Put event in relative db
            oKeyToEnter = New DatabaseEntry()
            oKeyToEnter.Data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dtTimestamp.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff")) 
            oDataToEnter = New DatabaseEntry(arTempArray)
            lstDbsEvents(oMyTag.iTagID).timeMachineBTreeDB.Put(oKeyToEnter, oDataToEnter)

        Catch ex As Exception
            LogErrorManagement.writeLogToFile("There was an error writing events to db", ex)
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first guess is that your database is for some reason completely memory mapped. The first thing your code shows is that your variables have a broader scope than the loop. Is that required? I am talking about `oKeyToEnter` and `oDataToEnter`.

Comment: probably it is memory mapped, but i don't know why... i tried changing the "cache size" and "page size" properties in db configuration but nothing seems changed